# WCF OperationContract that takes a base class

Tags: wcf

I've created a base class, and 2 inherited classes.  I want to create a WCF operation contract where the parameter is the base class.  Is there a decoration I can put on the parameter or classes that indicates that the value supplied must be one of the inherited classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy,

On the base class, you can use the known type attribute.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CircleType))]
[KnownType(typeof(TriangleType))]
public class CompanyLogo2
{
    [DataMember]
    private Shape ShapeOfLogo;
    [DataMember]
    private int ColorOfLogo;

}
```

Please reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

The are other ways of accomplishing this.

Here is a great MSDN article by Juval Lowy on Data Contract Inheritance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx

Comment: Fantastic!  I imagine there's no way to indicate the abstract base class can't be used is there?